# Efficient way to avoid inserting duplicate records

Tags: database

**Scenario of Records Insertion from one DB to another:**

Suppose I have 100,000 records in db1 and I am selecting a batch of records from database db1 and
inserting it into another database db2. By selecting a batch of records I mean I am selecting 1000 records 
at a time. Next time, I run the same query to select another batch of 1000 records, I want to start from 
record number 1001 as all the previous records 1000 records starting from row #1 have already been
inserted into db2.

So, basically, second time, I want to avoid copying the same number of record again in order to avoid
the duplicate records in the database db2.

In order to avoid the insertion of duplicate records, one approach, I am following right now is,
I have a integer value column named flag in my database db1 with a negative value, say for example -1 and as soon
as I grab 1000 records, I am updating the value to positive value , that is +1. So that, the second time
I will run the query to grab the next set of 1000 records, it will start from the record #1001.

I am wondering whether this is an efficient approach as everytime I run my query, my query will be checking 
all the records in db1 right from the start and then ultimately start grabbing the data from where it
will notice the start of negative value in the flag column. Please suggest if there is much more efficient
approach.

P.S: I am using JDBC to grab the records and insert it into another database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would not update the table in *db1* just for this purpouse.

I'd rather create another table either in *db1* or, maybe better, in *db2*, for control purpouses.

This way you will not need to cope with write access rigths in the original table in *db1* and/or with race or collision or multiuser conflict conditions.

The second table would record, for each extraction, the timestamp, tables involved, range extracted, user name, process name... and any other control information you might be interested.

Comment: :Isn't this approach going to consume more time than what I mentioned?

Comment: don't try to **prematurely optimize** because *""We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"* --Donald Knuth--en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth